# How to import SCSS library with assets in Angular application?

Tags: angular, sass, compilation

I have a SCSS library packaged as npm module, it has the following structure:

```
./index.scss
./partials/_foo.scss
./assets/foo.svg
```

And the `_foo.scss` contains a relative path to the image:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url('../assets/foo.svg');
}
```

When I import the `index.scss` file in my Angular application's `style.scss`, I'm getting a compilation error, because the compiler can't resolve the path to the image for some reason, however, the path is correct (relative to the original SCSS-file).

1. Is there a way to help Angular to resolve such images correctly?
2. Is there a way to improve the library somehow to make it easier to use in Angular?

I know I can use a variable to specify the base path in the library and then override it in the project where I import it, but I rather won't do it this way, because it adds more clutter to the library itself and requires the end-developer to override the variable in order to use the library.

Comment: better convert the **svg** to **base64** if you don't want to use the base path

Comment: @JohnVelasquez what if it's a large image and it's used only occasionally?

Comment: it really depends on you, but I think so far converting it to **base64** is the best solution.

Comment: @JohnVelasquez is there a way to convert images to base64 on compilation automatically?

Comment: No idea either, you could ask another question maybe someone can help you.

Comment: You don't need to base64 it, btw. If you `encodeURIComponent` on the string representation of the svg, you can use that in your data uri. Additionally, you might look at svgo to optimize the svg before encoding it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `url('~nameofnodemodule/assets/foo.svg')` webpack should be able to find it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I also know about this workaround, but I rather not use self-referencing in the library, cause it will make harder to e.g. rename the module later on and it violates the DRY principle.

Comment: I don't think you can do any better than that, at least for now.

Comment: This is very useful information and, yeah, I don't think you're going do any better than this unless you throw in some build process to insert the module name automatically.